# Why does sudo kill -15 on sh and docker-compose PIDs not stop Docker containers?

Tags: docker, process, system-calls, pid

I am running docker-compose up using the following command to set up my Docker containers:

`sudo -E env PATH="$PATH" sh -c "docker-compose up"`

When I check the processes using ps aux, I see the following hierarchy:

```
root     2505477  0.1  0.0   7916  3788 pts/4    S+   06:46   0:00 sudo -E env PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin sh -c docker-compose up
root     2505480  0.0  0.0   7916   520 pts/5    Ss   06:46   0:00 sudo -E env PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin sh -c docker-compose up
root     2505481  0.0  0.0   2316   816 pts/5    S+   06:46   0:00 sh -c docker-compose up
root     2505483  6.6  0.5 351976 48552 pts/5    Sl+  06:46   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/docker-compose up
```

And the process tree looks like this:

```
sudo(2505477)───sudo(2505480)───sh(2505481)───docker-compose(2505483)─┬─{docker-compose}(2505755)
                                                                      ├─{docker-compose}(2505756)
                                                                      └─{docker-compose}(2505757)
```

When I attempt to stop the Docker containers by killing the shell process and the docker-compose process using:

`sudo kill -15 2505481 2505483`

The Docker containers do not stop. However, if I only target the docker-compose process with:

`sudo kill -15 2505483`

It does stop the containers. Why does killing both the sh process (2505481) and docker-compose process (2505483) not stop the Docker containers?

Any insights into what might be happening here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: OT: Don't run docker or docker-compose as root. Add yourself to the docker group instead.

Comment: this is an isolation of a program, the code would be running the docker image of another project in a go -code, thus adding the docker as root

Comment: The only reason you need sudo here is because your current user does not have access to the docker socket, which is owned by group `docker`. Add yourself to that group so you can run `docker build` and others without special privileges.

Comment: @Botje It's all but trivial to `docker run` a container that roots the entire host, and it's appropriate to require `sudo` permissions to do that.  I don't think the user's group membership is related to this problem.

Comment: @DavidMaze I marked my comment as "OT" (off-topic) for that reason. I had not expected to spend multiple comments defending the common practice of "don't run things as root if you don't have to".